Can Anyone Recommend iPhone Setup for Recording Guitar Videos over MP3 Tracks?
Strictly as a hobby, I record video of guitar performances, mostly for my YouTube channel and for the past several years I've been using the following products with mixed results:

IKMultimedia Amplitube
IKMultimedia iRig Recorder
Garageband
Audiobus
IPhone 11 - IOS v17.5.1

Generally when recording simple videos using the iRig recorder alone the quality is acceptable.
The problems arise when integrating different audio sources like Amplitube and MP3 recordings into iRig Recorder to record videos that the recording quality really deteriorates.
I was advised years ago to use Audiobus and use a configuration simlar to this:
Amplitube-> iRig Recorder->Garageband

For the most part this works, but with less than optimal results again in both audio and video quality (Pops, Clicks, Marginal Video Quality)
There doesn't seem to be any documentation regarding best practices from ikMultimedia regarding this topic which is a bit frustrating.
Today I was experimenting with Garageband and instead of using Audiobus, I added Amplitube and iRig Recorder directly into Garageband:


And instead of playing the MP3 through Amplitube, I imported the MP3 into Garageband as an audio track.
I thought that I might be onto something since the audio sounded great and I could hear my guitar, but when I went to record in iRig Recorder, the audio source from Garageband wasn't being recognized in iRig Recorder and the video recording contained only my guitar.
I thought there must be an output setting for Garageband, however I can't seem to find that setting...Also not sure if the monitor setting is significant but tried several different configurations there without much luck.
Thanks in advance.


It's not clear if you're asking for a recommendation, or if you're just asking for how to find/use a couple of settings in GarageBand.

It would be good if you'd mentioned the IOS device you are using - generation etc.

If you have an extra mic, I'd recommend using the iphone as a video recorder, capturing the audio separately at the same time, and combining all the sources "in post."

@AndyBonner the beauty of this method is that you are getting an instant video recording with audio mix based on your own configuration. Audiobus has also a mixer so you can set the levels etc. Great for casual video recordings as no post editing steps or audio-video sync is neccessary.

Audiobus is in principle a great tool but considering limited processing power of IOS devices it very often just cannot handle some configurations while keeping low latency and quality of audio and video intact. I had mixed results but with this config here

I've had best results.
The apps used are:

Audioshare
BiasFX (you can replace with amplitube)
IRig Recorder

As you can see you set up two parallel streams one with Audioshare playing backing track (MP3 or whatever format) and BiasFX used for processing guitar sound and both streams are directed into IRigRecorder.
With this setup I was able to play backing track, play guitar via IRigHD and record video and audio from Audioshare and BiasFX in one step on a single Iphone.
It wasn't always perfect - sometimes it was glitching and I had to restart the audiobus or some apps in the workflow but mostly results were ok.
I think Garageband is quite heavy piece of software to use in these type of workflows that's why I prefer smaller apps for this.
But in general the problems you are experiencing are caused by the IOS device not being able to handle the workflow and keep the apps running in parallel and with low latency and high quality. It is very much to ask for as IOS devices are not that great at running multiple apps in parallel.
